# About XML layout & custom android class

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I'm using Eclipse IDE.
How I should define class, initialized (for example) in `activity_main.xml` ?
Lets presume, in `activity_main.xml` I have definition of ListView object like:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListViewAction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</ListView>
```

Normally I could handle this in file `MainActivity.java` and it's fine.

But I want to split code to different `.java` file and create class extending ListView.
So, I create new java class file and what I should put in that class to overload ListView ?
If I place standard class definition in that new java file, it doesn't work:

```
public class ListViewAction extends ListView {

    public ListViewAction(Context context) {
        super(context);
        System.out.println("ListViewAction()");         
    }       
}
```

How I should correctly define class in new java file and XML?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to customize your own `ListView`, you must to do these things:

### 1 . Extends the new class with the widget and attach the context:

```
public class myOwnListView extends ListView { 
    final Context context;

    public myOwnListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public myOwnListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public myOwnListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

### 2 . Change your layout's ListView:

```
// instead of
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListViewAction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// you need to do as below  
<com.my.package.name.myOwnListView
    android:id="@+id/ListViewAction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

### 3 . Use it in your onCreate method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // initialize your ListView:
    myOwnListView myListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // find your view in your layout:
        listview = (myOwnListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewAction); 

        // set to an adapter...
        listview.setAdapter( [...] );

        // more stuff
    }

}
```

### 4 . Avoid some bugs:

In your layout, try to always set the height of a widget as `GridView` or `ListView` to the height of the parent layout with `match_parent` / `fill_parent`.

---

With this project *[HeaderListView](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView)* by **tokou** or this one *[HFGridView](https://github.com/SergeyBurish/HFGridView)* by **Sergey Burish**, you can see how does it works and you will have a best approach to do what you want.
Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Prince. The last part for ListView is described [on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=40m45s) by Romain Guy, it's preferable to use `layout_weight` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you added `MyListView`:

```
package my.app;

public class MyListView extends ListView {
  // ...
}
```

You can reference it in the XML using the full class name:

```
<my.app.MyListView
   ...
/>
```